# How to write performance tests on rest CRUD API using jmeter?

Tags: java, rest, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to test all the CRUD APIs using JMeter, like CREATE, READ, UPDATE & DELETE in Jmeter

I have used an autoincrement variable and used the same in all the operations but I wanted to know the correct way.

The challenge here is it executing all the APIs parallelly instead of the first CREAT then READ, UPDATE & Delete

How can we write nested or ordered tests in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

Before "reading" something you need to "create" something, don't you? And if you "delete" something you won't be able to "update" it.

So you should create 4 [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers:

1. Create
2. Read
3. Update
4. Delete

each JMeter thread (virtual user) will run them sequentially. But if you [add more than one thread](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) there will be **concurrency**, i.e. first user will be creating one item, second will be updating another item, third user will be reading yet another item, etc.

Just in case, it's possible to make all these actions with 1 user at the same time using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) but you won't get successful results.